# how to convert base10 number into an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, radix, typeconverter

The meaning is : How to store in a single database field, multiple value as, for example, Optin data.

In order to do that, i've to know how to code and decode the value.
I've an array with different optin values:

```
$optin = array (
    '1' => 'SMS',
    '2' => 'Email',
    '4' => 'Mail',
    '8' => 'AppsPushNotif',
    '16' => 'Partners',
    '32' => 'Gaming Partners'
);
```

ie.: I'll store,in optin field :
- '7'  if the user is opt-in for SMS,Email and Mail (4+2+1)
or
- '40' for AppsPushNotif and Gaming_Partners

I would like found a way to decode 7 or 40 values into an array with optin's arrays values.

Many thanks

PS: Thanks to Cyclone for the solution :

```
$output = '';
$value = 40;
$keys = array_keys($food);  

foreach($keys as $key) {   
    if($value & $key) $output .= $food[$key].',';  
}  

print rtrim($output, ',');
```

Comment: This should work: `$output = ''; $value = 40; $keys = array_keys($food); foreach($keys as $key) { if($value & $key) $output .= $food[$key].','; } print rtrim($output, ',');`

Comment: You should try to accept my answer if you think it solved your question =)

Answer (score 0):

A solution in one line to unpack `$value` into individual values that appear as keys in `$optin`:

```
$value = 40;

$keys = array_map(
    function($i) { return 1 << $i; },
    array_keys(array_filter(str_split(strrev(decbin($value)))))
);

print_r($keys);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 32
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$output = ''; 
$value = 40; 
$keys = array_keys($food); 

foreach($keys as $key) { 
  if($value & $key) 
    $output .= $food[$key].','; 
} 
print rtrim($output, ',');
```